# Corona drag and drop tile in container

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have asked a similar question before, but I need some help to clean it up. I images like scrabble tiles which I can drag and drop in my container, but I'm duplicating a lot of code. I also want to know how to be able to drop a tile in any number of containers instead of one specific container. Here is a snippet of the code. Can someone please help, because I want to avoid duplicating code and I need to work out how to drop a tile on multiple containers. *Edit* would like each container to read the letter and combine for a full word

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local posX, posY = 100, 200
local sizeX, sizeY = 40, 40
local posX1, posY1 = 150, 200
local posx, posy = 10, 50

local container = display.newRoundedRect( posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, 3 )
container:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
container.strokeWidth = 3
container:setStrokeColor(100, 100, 100)

local container2 = display.newRoundedRect( posX1, posY1, sizeX, sizeY, 3 )
container:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
container2.strokeWidth = 3
container2:setStrokeColor(100, 100, 100)



local myObject = display.newImage("letters/B.png" , 150, 10)
local myObject2 = display.newImage("letters/a.png" , 10, 10)
local myObject3 = display.newImage("letters/C.png" , 200, 10)

-- touch listener function
function myObject:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        self.markX = self.x    -- store x location of object
        self.markY = self.y    -- store y location of object

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        self.x, self.y = x, y    -- move object based on calculations above

        if (((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
            container:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
        else
            container:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
        end

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        -- main condition: I calculated 3 areas to atract the object to the target container, 2 areas that atract it when it's 1/3 in the target and 1 area that atract it when it's 1/4 in the target
        if (((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
            self.x, self.y = posX + (sizeX/2), posY + (sizeY/2);
        end

    end

    return true
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------test---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- touch listener function
function myObject2:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        self.markX = self.x    -- store x location of object
        self.markY = self.y    -- store y location of object

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        self.x, self.y = x, y    -- move object based on calculations above
        if (((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
            container2:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
        else
            container2:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
        end

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        -- main condition: I calculated 3 areas to atract the object to the target container, 2 areas that atract it when it's 1/3 in the target and 1 area that atract it when it's 1/4 in the target
        if (((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
            self.x, self.y = posX1 + (sizeX/2), posY1 + (sizeY/2);
        end

    end

    return true
end
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function myObject3:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        self.markX = self.x    -- store x location of object
        self.markY = self.y    -- store y location of object

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        self.x, self.y = x, y    -- move object based on calculations above
        if (((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
            container2:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
        else
            container2:setFillColor( 0,0,255 )
        end

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        -- main condition: I calculated 3 areas to atract the object to the target container, 2 areas that atract it when it's 1/3 in the target and 1 area that atract it when it's 1/4 in the target
        if (((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((2/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((2/3) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/3) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((2/3) * sizeY)))) or ((x >= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 - ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y >= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 - ((1/2) * sizeY))) and (x <= ((sizeX/2) + posX1 + ((1/2) * sizeX))) and (y <= ((sizeY/2) + posY1 + ((1/2) * sizeY))))) then
            self.x, self.y = posX1 + (sizeX/2), posY1 + (sizeY/2);

        end

    end

    return true
end

myObject:addEventListener( "touch", myObject )
myObject3:addEventListener( "touch", myObject3 )
myObject2:addEventListener( "touch", myObject2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using tables for this.  You need have all your tiles in a table, so you are using 
    myObject[1]
    myObject[2]

etc.  Then you could use a single touch function where event.target is the object that was touched (i.e. if someone touched myObject[2] that would be referenced inside your function as event.target.  then if your containers are also in a table:

```
container[1]
container[2]
```

then inside your touch handler, you could do a loop like:

```
for i = 1, #container do
      -- do your code to check to see if your object is in your container
end
```

You should be able to get away with a single touch handler function using a combination of the fact that event.target is your tile and looping over the containers so you can test against all of them.